# Appear a foreign key in a table with no reason

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the next entities:

- **Publication:** saves every publication.
- **Category:** list of categories.
- **PublicationCategory:** links every publication with their assigned categories.

I only have 2 fields in **Category**:

- **Id:** is not a foreing key, is a primary key,
- **Name:** name of the cathegory.

**Category.cs**

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is when I create the database, the table generated for Category.cs has a field more: **PublicationId**, which is a foreing key to **Publication**.

[image]

I have uploaded a mock to GitHub: https://github.com/johndoe52332/publicationIdAppear

Comment: It's because your `Publication` class contains `public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }` property which defines one-to-many relationship.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, but I'm not mapping the property. I only want collections for access to the tables from this.context.Publications and do complex queries without nesting this.context.TableName

Comment: that does not make sense. a one-to-many relationship requires a FK property, so it is entirely normal. You saying you want to "navigate" your context with this property also means it is meant as a navigation property, and for query creation and a bunch of other issues the mapped navigation property makes the FK column necessary. How do you want EF to establish the relationship, magic?